# PHP form control retaining information when session expires

Tags: php, session

I'm getting lost in form control and I think I'm making it far more complicated than it needs to be, hoping someone can help me?

I have a simple "View Product" page which has a button to create a review, the button link is created dynamically such as:

```
"newreview.php?productid=1"
```

When I click this button, my *newreview* page receives the productid via $_GET. The user then enters the review details for which I post back to the same *newreview* page to validate and process. To retain the productid (as the form is now POST I use a hidden field).

So I now get back via $_POST the review details and the productid and this works fine.

However a user must be signed in to post a review, so at the start of the newreview page I check if the user is signed in and If not store the current page in the session ('REQUEST_URI' stored in **lastpage**) and direct to the signin page.

If after signing-in the session has a **lastpage** element I redirect the user back to the previous page.

If the user is not logged in or the session is expired when first submitting a review, the **lastpage** session field contains the URI parameters (as its a $_GET) so this works fine.

But what do I do if the session expires while the user is writing a review, this has just happened? When they click submit and the page is posted back, the session is expired so they are redirected to the sign-in page but when it attempts to return all the information (including critically the productid is gone)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try storing the $_POST content in a cookie, then you can check if the cookie exists and that the user is redirected back from login. Grab the cookies content and then do the submit.

#### OR

Store the posted data in a session variable to save the roundtrip of the data. The users state when logging in is mid-submit so this should be easy to store as well, automatically triggering the completion of the submit when the user returns to the review page.